# Typeof check vs null check

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I've learned to always check variables in Javascript like this:

```
function x(variable){
   if(typeof variable !== "undefined" && variable !== null)...
}
```

A new collegue now said it's easier and better to just do this:

```
function x(variable){
   if(variable != null)
}
```

Is this really the same? How can this work?

Thanks

Comment: A suggetion, I think if(variable) should also do the same.

Comment: No, what if the variable is really undefined? than you would get an error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null and undefined are two [primitive datatypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) in JavaScript.

---

An Example [From Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

```
var x;
if (x === undefined) {
   // these statements execute
}
else {
   // these statements do not execute
}
```

The strict equality operator rather than the standard equality operator must be used here, because `x == undefined` also checks whether x is null, while strict equality doesn't. `null` is not equivalent to `undefined`.

---

```
function x(variable){
   if(variable != null) // variable would be both null and undefined for comparison
}
```

The above example I think works because you are not using strict comparison. So in short both your examples are not the same but could give same result. It all depends on whether your logical requirement is a strict comparison or not.

Answer (score 0):

`function x(variable){
   if(typeof variable !== "undefined" && variable !== null)...
}`

Above will check whether variable is exists or is it declared and if so not null. This is a good approach if you are unsure about the variable declaration.

`function x(variable){
   if(variable != null)
}`

Above will just check whether the variable is not null. This is good only if you are sure variable is declared at first place.

Extra bit,

```
return value === null || value === undefined;
```

Above is for null or undefined.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that the first one can be safely used to check global variable

```
> foo // -> ReferenceError
> foo != null // -> ReferenceError
> typeof foo !== 'undefined' && foo !== null // -> false
```

But in your example it does not matter because empty function argument is always `undefined`

Comment: ok. 
A strange thing I noticed is this: undefined == null is true. How can this be?

Comment: Javascript weak typing, there are even worse examples, e.g. Array(3) == ',,'

Comment: Always compare types and values with `===` and `!==` to avoid issues like `undefined == null` being `true`